# python 2.7 issue with decode utf8

Tags: python

i have problem with decode utf-8 , i try everything on the web and it's still not working ,

i read line from file , this line contains utf8 characters that are not appears

if i set this line manually the characters appears , what are the differences and how can i solve this ?

this code is working :

```
b="test Test\hello\\\xd7\x92\xd7\x99\xd7\x95\xd7\x9c \xd7\x9b\xd7\x9e\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa\xd7\x99.csv"
print(type(b))
print (b)
```

the resulat :

test Test\hello\גיול כמותי.csv

this code is not working :

```
f = open('C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\Logs\SyslogCatchAll.txt')
for line in f :
print(line)
```

the resault is :

bro_files Test\hello\\xd7\x92\xd7\x99\xd7\x95\xd7\x9c \xd7\x9b\xd7\x9e\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa\xd7\x99.csv

the 2 lines are the same , the differences is that i read it from file

Answer (score 0):

For opening a file with utf-8 you need to use `codecs` as:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\Logs\SyslogCatchAll.txt', encoding="utf-8")
```

Or, you may try with `io` module, as suggested by @ PM 2Ring

```
import io
io.open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\Logs\SyslogCatchAll.txt", encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) is better than `codecs.open`.

Comment: try this also , still not working , this time i'm getting type unicode,and the same line with xd7\x92\x99....

Comment: Then try with `io.open()` as suggested by @PM2Ring

Comment: It would be interesting to know, How `io.open()` is a better choice over `codecs.open()` ? @PM2Ring